Vue animation :: warning issue
I have a working example of VUE JS menu animation, however the problem is I have two root elements inside the menu component, and I get this warning:

[Vue warn]: Runtime directive used on component with non-element root node. The directives will not function as intended.

App.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Menu from './Menu.vue'

const menuVisible = ref(false)
const toggle = () => {
  menuVisible.value = !menuVisible.value
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Side bar animation</h1>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle menu</button>
  <Menu :visible="menuVisible" @update:visible="toggle" v-show="menuVisible"/>
</template>

Menu.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import {  toRefs, watchEffect, onBeforeUnmount, onMounted } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  visible: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false
  }
});

const { visible } = toRefs(props);

const emit = defineEmits(['update:visible']);

const hidemenuBar = () => {
  emit('update:visible', false);
};

watchEffect(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = visible.value ? 'hidden' : 'auto';
  document.body.style.paddingRight = visible.value ? '15px' : '0px';
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  document.body.style.paddingRight = '0px';
});

</script>

<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="visible" class="menubar-overlay" @click="hidemenuBar"></div>
  </transition>
  <transition name="slide">
    <div class="menubar-container" v-if="visible">
      <div class="menubar__header">
        <h2 class="menu-headline">Menu</h2>
        <div>
          <i @click="hidemenuBar" class="cursor-pointer pi pi-times p-2"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
       <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
       </ul>
       <button @click="hidemenuBar">Close</button>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style scoped>
.slide-enter-from,
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide-enter-to,
.slide-leave-from {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide-enter-active,
.slide-leave-active {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

/* menubar */
.menubar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menubar-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}

.menubar__header {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
</style>


However, the problem is when I wrap the transitions in Menu.vue into a template the animation doesn't work at all... if I wrap it in a div, it only works one-way (slide-in, no slide-out)
Any idea how to fix it?
Playground: here

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

The warning means it doesn't know which root element to apply the v-show to.  You should handle it within Menu component instead of at the parent level... but wait, you already are. v-if="visible" is on both of your root elements:
 <transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="visible" class="menubar-overlay" @click="hidemenuBar"></div>
  </transition>
  <transition name="slide">
    <div class="menubar-container" v-if="visible">
    ...
  </transition>

You can just delete v-show="menuVisible" from the parent component since it's not needed.
updated Playground
